# Is there a better way to create a loan amortization table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, amortization

I'm trying to create a simple amortization of a loan.  For some reason, my code stops working after a few periods.  Starting on period 2006-04-30, my code is not recognizing the beginning balance and is not calculating interest on this balance nor is it calculating an ending balance.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range("2006-01-01", "2011-12-31", freq='M')})
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.set_index(data['date'], inplace=True)

orig_balance = 1000000
interest_rate = .06
day_count = 30/360
data['monthly_principal_pmt'] = 10000
date_cut_off = '2006-01-31'

data['beginning_balance']  = 0

for row in data:
    
    data.at[date_cut_off,'beginning_balance'] = orig_balance
    
    data['ending_balance'] = np.maximum(data['beginning_balance'] - data['monthly_principal_pmt'],0)
    
    data['monthly_interest_pmt'] = data['beginning_balance'] * day_count * interest_rate 
    
    data['beginning_balance'] = data['ending_balance'].shift()
```

Comment: You iterate on row and don't use it, normal ? Also `row` is in fact the column name, that's what happen when iterate over the DF

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help!  this now works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range("2006-01-01", "2011-12-31", freq='M')})
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.set_index(data['date'], inplace=True)

orig_balance = 1000000
interest_rate = .06
day_count = 30/360
data['monthly_principal_pmt'] = 10000
date_cut_off = '2006-01-31'

data['beginning_balance']  = 0

for yr in range(1,72):
    
    data.at[date_cut_off,'beginning_balance'] = orig_balance
    
    data['ending_balance'] = np.maximum(data['beginning_balance'] - data['monthly_principal_pmt'],0)
    #data['ending_balance'] = data['beginning_balance'] - data['monthly_principal_pmt']

    
    
    data['monthly_interest_pmt'] = data['beginning_balance'] * day_count * interest_rate 
    
    data['beginning_balance'] = data['ending_balance'].shift()
```